# angularjs $scope variable for multiple views from a single controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs.Presently I am building spa using angularjs and mvc4.
Can I use $scope variables in different views in angularjs? Plz help me.

Comment: You could store your variables in a service or on your rootScope, services are preferred as polluting the rootScope is bad practice in angular.

Comment: Added another demo showing single variable across different views

Answer (score 0):

$scope is limited to controller. Try using [$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24rootScope).

Answer (score 0):

To communicate variables across different controllers register a `factory`, then pass the factory object to a $scope in each controller.

Simple demo http://plnkr.co/edit/PdDmUz?p=preview

**Update**: Another demo, showing single variable use in different views using service/factory. http://plnkr.co/edit/P2UudS?p=preview

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h3>Controller 1</h3>
    Check me, to check both: 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected.data" />
    <pre>selected.data: {{selected.data}}</pre>

<h3>Controller 2</h3>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl2">
    Or, check me: 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected2.data" />
    <pre>selected2.data: {{selected2.data}}</pre>
</div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,uiFieldState) {
    $scope.selected = uiFieldState.uiObject;
})

app.controller('MainCtrl2', function($scope,uiFieldState) {
    $scope.selected2 = uiFieldState.uiObject;
})

app.factory('uiFieldState', function () {
    return {uiObject: {data: null} }
});
```

Comment: my question is how a single $scope variable to use in different view not different controller.For Example I have one  Employee controller and two views Employeelist.html and EmployeeDetails.html.In Employee controller I have two scope variables $scope.Employeelist used in EmployeeList and $scope.Employee to be used in EmployeeDetails.html .But In my case EmployeeDetails.html can not bind with $scope.candidate.I have checked with Batarang.Data is coming properly from server.

Comment: A factory will pass the variable to a single $scope in another view. The different view must have a controller for the $scope, so what I have posted will work.

Answer (score -1):

Angular $scope is prototypically inherited for child scopes , therefore basically you can have a parent $scope which is shared among several  child scopes .

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
    <div ng-include="view1.html"></div>
    <div ng-include="view2.html"></div>
</div>
```

Here the `parentController` is accessible to both views.